# Formatters in Python

Tags: python-2.7, formatter

I have this line of code:

> > > formatter = "%r %r %r %r"

print formatter % (1, 2, 3, 4)
print formatter % ("one", "two", "three", "four")
print formatter % (True, False, False, True)
print formatter % (formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter)
print formatter % (
    "I had this thing for you.",
    "That you could type up right.",
    "But it didn't sing.",
    "So I said goodnight."
)<<<

and the output for the last 4 lines is:

> > > 'I had this thing for you.' 'That you could type up right.' "But it didn't sing." 'So I said goodnight.' <<<

I want to understand why does the third sentence display in double quotation while the others are in single quotation.

I have tried removing the double quotation, but it does not yield the expected result.

```
print formatter % (1, 2, 3, 4)
print formatter % ("one", "two", "three", "four")
print formatter % (True, False, False, True)
print formatter % (formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter)
print formatter % (
    "I had this thing for you.",
    "That you could type up right.",
    "But it didn't sing.",
    "So I said goodnight."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have apostrophe `'` inside the string. If you remove it, it will be printed as `'But it didnt sing.'`
It's to differentiate between string limits. It would be somewhat confusing if it was printed with `'`: `'But it didn't sing.'`

PS. If you add both `'` and `"` signs to your string then thing get even more interesting. Try yourself.